# ffmpeg to get an HEVC RTSP stream into an mkv container

Tags: video, ffmpeg, matroska, rtsp

I'm trying to copy an hevc video from an RTSP feed into an mkv container.

This **works**: `rtsp(hevc) -> out.hevc` then `out.hevc -> out.mkv`

This **doesn't work** `rtsp(hevc) -> out.mkv`

Working below:

```
ffmpeg  -nostats  -hide_banner -loglevel info -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://xx -an -vcodec copy -bsf:v hevc_metadata=tick_rate=1 /tmp/out.hevc -y
[hevc @ 0x564864b07680] VPS 0 does not exist
    Last message repeated 1 times
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://xx':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.040000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 1280x720, 2 fps, 1 tbr, 90k tbn, 2 tbc
Output #0, hevc, to '/tmp/out.hevc':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 1280x720, q=2-31, 2 fps, 1 tbr, 2 tbn, 2 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  110 fps=1.2 q=-1.0 Lsize=   10165kB time=00:01:48.50 bitrate= 767.5kbits/s speed=1.15x    
video:10165kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
```

and checking the file:

```
ffprobe -hide_banner /tmp/out.hevc
Input #0, hevc, from '/tmp/out.hevc':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 1280x720, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 1200k tbn, 1 tbc
```

perfect! Putting it into an matroska container:

```
ffmpeg  -nostats  -hide_banner -loglevel error -i /tmp/out.hevc -an -vcodec copy -bsf:v hevc_metadata=tick_rate=1 /tmp/out.mkv -y
```

checking:

```
ffprobe -hide_banner /tmp/out.mkv 
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/tmp/out.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:01:50.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 757 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 1280x720, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 1k tbn, 1 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:01:50.000000000
```

however when I attempt to directly go from RTSP(hevc) -> Matroska(hevc):

```
ffmpeg  -nostats  -hide_banner -loglevel info -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://xx -an -vcodec copy -bsf:v hevc_metadata=tick_rate=1 -f matroska /tmp/out.mkv -y 
[hevc @ 0x55fda6886840] VPS 0 does not exist
    Last message repeated 1 times
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://xx':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.040000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 1280x720, 2 fps, 1 tbr, 90k tbn, 2 tbc
Output #0, matroska, to '/tmp/out.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 1280x720, q=2-31, 2 fps, 1 tbr, 1k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[matroska @ 0x55fda6888900] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
frame=   51 fps=1.3 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4637kB time=00:00:49.00 bitrate= 775.2kbits/s speed=1.28x    
video:4636kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.034634%
```

and invalid file is created:

```
ffprobe -hide_banner /tmp/out.mkv
[AVBSFContext @ 0x55b897eb1980] No start code is found.
/tmp/out.mkv: Invalid data found when processing input
```

The `Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0` warning is concerning,.

But I guess this is possible, but I've been unable to find the right incantation of bytestream magic to make this work. Ultimately I'm trying to produce a segmented seekable matroska files (`-f segment -segment_format mkv -segment_time 3600 -strftime 1 camera01-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.mkv`) but seem to be stuck deeper in ffmpeg.

I've tried `-live 1` and also the `hevc_mp4toannexb` to no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may have to roundtrip via MP4.

Comment: I have tried that too:  `ffmpeg  -nostats  -hide_banner -loglevel info -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://xxx -an -vcodec copy -bsf:v hevc_metadata=tick_rate=1  /tmp/out.mp4 -y`  yields  `ffprobe -hide_banner /tmp/out.mp4 
[AVBSFContext @ 0x563dc3eec4c0] No start code is found.
/tmp/out.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input`

Comment: incase it's useful here is [out.hevc](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12mJMmTqIG3gGtYVW0ZafZbKvv7RlVgUD/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The dumped stream won't help. Is the rtsp still open?

Comment: opened again: 
 rtsp://test:stackexchange123@f17gw.imaginator.com:554/ISAPI/streaming/channels/101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a piped roundtrip

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://xx -an -vcodec copy -bsf:v hevc_metadata=tick_rate=1 -f hevc - | ffmpeg -f hevc -i - -c copy out.mkv -y`

ffmpeg looks for codec extradata only in first packet but the RTSP input appears to not have it.

Comment: Works well. Now incorporated at https://github.com/imaginator/system/blob/master/salt/motion/files/record-video.service

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't add a comment, I want to share that this bug has been reported for 3 years now. (Right around this question was originally asked)

[#7974 new defect RTSP h265 input produces invalid MP4 output with -c copy](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7974#comment:1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).